# Removing space between table doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

I've got a grid that I want to be as absolute as possible; preferably with 1px between each `td`. My issue though is that seemingly nothing I do reduces the space between the `td` or evens the larger space between `tr`.

When you click Update Preview in my code the desired result should be even spacing between the `td`; I want the `td` to have the same size as the canvases. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/cqvktzLe/), and my code:

**Fixed Snippet:**

```js
var canvas = [];
canvas.push(new fabric.Canvas('c0'));
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  canvas.push(new fabric.StaticCanvas('sc' + i));
}

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: '#F5F5F5',
  width: 187.5,
  height: 318.75
});

canvas[0].add(rect);

$('#update').click(function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(canvas[0]);
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    canvas[i].loadFromJSON(json);
  }
});

$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'myfile.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  border: 0px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;

}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 637.5px;
  width: 825px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="update">Update Preview</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>


<div id="imagesave">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="c0" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc1" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc2" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc3" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc4" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc5" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc6" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas id="sc7" width="187.5" height="318.75"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```